# AES Encryption in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, aes

my iOS app is connected to a web service. App is written in objective-c.  Server sending a string that has encrypted using `AES` encryption using a password string and IV string. I want to decrypt that string in this app side. How can I do it?

Please help me. Thanks

**UPDATE**

This is how I decrypt my string

```
NSData *url1Data = [strEncrypted dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *url1DataDecrypt = [[StringEncryption alloc] decrypt:url1Data  key:Hashkey iv:iv];
NSString * decryptedText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:url1DataDecrypt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Have a look on https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor

Comment: I checked. But what it says How do I manually set the IV?

You don't. does that mean I can't use my IV string here?

Comment: if you have the password and just decrypt it; where have you been stuck at?

Comment: in server side the string sending me is encrypted using a password and IV value I have to use that particular password and IV to decrypt it. But this RNCrypto seems doesn't take the IV

Comment: RNCryptor is a good solution if you can use it on both sides but if you have no control over both it probably is not a usable solution. Since you tagged as ObjC use Common Crypto from the Security framework. There are several implementation examples on SO. Try a solution and if you have difficulty post your code along with test data: key, iv, mode, padding and data before and after decryption in hexadecimal.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. I used CryptLib https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption because my server side is using this library for C#. Encryption is working for me. And I get the response from the service. But when I try to decrypt that string using the same password and IV I get just null

Comment: The code only uses SHA-256 for password extension to a key, current practice is to use a method such as PBKDF2. Base64 has been available directly from NSData for many years now, there is no need for a proprietary version. On the plus side it does use Common Crypto.

Answer (score -2):

You need generate Public key certificate & distribute to both side user FBEncrypt Library to decrypt data using AES Algorithm it is secure & Easy to implement [FBEncrypt Library](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRn53N0vXMAhUFK48KHcCIBbQQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fyfme%2FBTCChinaTrade%2Ftree%2Fmaster%2FBTCChinaTrade%2FBTCChinaTrade%2FClasses%2FLibs%2FFBEncrypt&usg=AFQjCNHph31tAnhqNQP5HWzGDMFKZ3D4pg&sig2=F17mAiCq47K5oJwrxOxKOg).

Comment: My service side use CryptLib.https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption. Here encryption is working for me. but decryption returns null always. But in C# and Android decryption is working

Comment: AES is a symmetric algorithm and does not use a "Public key certificate", it uses a simple shared key.